# How can I decrease "Connecting" and "Waiting" times from AJAX requests to the Server?

Tags: ajax

My actual script execution time, is less then a microsecond and yet, the total time, the response takes is about 250 ms - 1000 times more, on a typical ajaxcall.  Even in environments where I have a reliable T1 connection, the responses still take 50-100ms.

Background info:

- Call are being made via POST/GET through AJAX, jQuery
- Backend is PHP/mysql on the Joyent servers.
- the information shown below comes from firebug, net tab.

DNS Lookup = 0
Connecting = 46ms
Sending = 0ms  
Waiting = 172ms 
Receiving = 0ms

Comment: Are you testing the connecting and waiting times on a deployed version of your software (on the Internet)?  On your box?  On a lan?  How many hops is it to your server?

Comment: No, i'm testing the deployed version on the internet, on the joyent servers.  The connecting time, may be dependent on the number of hops but the waiting time shouldn't be.  Waiting starts when the request gets to the server, right?

Answer (score 0):

you need to move closer to the servers. :)  Sounds like the speed of light is your bottleneck.

Have a look at the trace route of your network packets to the server.

Comment: but if that were the case, then shouldn't the receiving time be much higher?  The way I understood it, the "Waiting" time is the time after the request gets to the server but before it comes back to the client.  Since the waiting time, is the limiting factor, it means there's something going on, on the server that is taking a while to process.

Comment: but that something thats going on, on the server, happens before, or possibly after my code executes.

Comment: background info: from the command line, the ellapsed execution time is .06 seconds, still 10 times less then the amount of the waiting time.